# Draw a possibly non-simple graph given its degree sequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider the following sequence:

(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)

Does there exist a graph with the above degree sequence?
If so, draw an example of such a graph; otherwise, briefly explain why no such graph exists.

I was able to draw a graph with trial and error since it doesn't need to be a simple graph. I was just wondering if there was some steps that I can follow so that ill always be able to find such a graph without waisting time doing trial and error. the only other questions I found related to this is for simple graphs only.  But here, we are allowed loops and parallel edges.

Comment: Your question doesn't require you to draw such a graph... just to state whether it is possible or impossible to find one.  By example:  Can you find an undirected graph with degree sequence $\{0, 1\}$?  Why or why not?  Do you need to draw a graph to answer that question?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but you _can_ draw the graph with the OP's degree sequence?

Comment: This looks like a standard homework problem about the Erdõs-Gallai theorem (and its constructive proof)

Comment: @ahulpke Erdos-Gallai is the corresponding much more complicated idea for simple graphs, but otherwise I agree.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It says that if its possible then draw an example...

Comment: @user20194358:  Minor point, but I would advocate following the flow of the question:  First *SHOW* conceptually a graph can be drawn, *THEN* draw it.  Working "backwards" by trial and error may skip a step where some mathematical concept is to be used.  This flow may be useful for much larger problems, where trial and error is inappropriate.

Comment: If you're allowed multiple loops from each vertex, then there's a trivial solution to any degree sequence. I guess an additional assumption should be made.

Comment: @Fnacool what would be the trivial solution? since a loop counts for 2 degrees

Comment: @DavidG.Stork i see what you mean but we just started talking about graphs and the only thing we can use really to show that a graph ( non simple ) cant exist is using the handshaking theorem, otherwise I assume that i can . however if they ask for a simple graph then i can explain why it will wont be without using any theorems and just logic and reasoning